# Windows shared folder password location

Tags: windows-7, networking, passwords, shared-folders

as title says..
I browsed a shared folder (from win to win) using combination of username/password, where are they stored?

I'd like to reset it so the next time I try to browse the folder I'll get the login box...

Edit:
I'm on Windows 7... 
On Windows XP you can delete the stored password from useraccount -> Manage network password...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `credential` into the Start Menu search box, you should get Credential Manager which is what the "Manage network password" dialog now gives. That *should* show any credentials that have been saved. Another method of browsing these credentials is [the Nirsoft Network Password Recovery tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/network_password_recovery.html)

As far as I can tell, if your normal Windows username/password is the same as the remote one, it's not saved anywhere and you can't make it "forget" (it uses it automatically and only prompts if that one isn't valid). Others should be visible, although after deleting them you may need to reboot - I found that my shares remained connected and drives remained mapped until I rebooted.